# Is there a dummy comparison variable in python and pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe `df` as follows:

```
C1  C2  C3
a1  a   d
b1  b   e
c1  c   f
```

If I do `df[df['C1'] == 'a1']` I get

```
C1  C2  C3
a1  a   d
```

Is there some way of comparing things so that if I do `df[df['C1'] == 'what should I use here']`, I get all rows. i.e. I am looking for a dummy comparison variable so that comparison statement is ignored and all rows are returned.

```
C1  C2  C3
a1  a   d
b1  b   e
c1  c   f
```

Edit: As the code is grandfathered, I need to use only `==` comparison statement. I can't use `!=`. The comparison variable is coming through a for loop and I can insert a dummy variable in the for loop if available.

This is what the original code is which I can't modify:

```
dfNew = []
for ii in ['a1', 'a2']:
 for jj in ['a', 'b']:
  dfNew.append(df[(df['C1'] == ii) & (df['C2'] == jj)])
```

What I am trying to achieve in `dfNew` is to also append values where if there was a dummy variable in `['a1', 'a2', 'dummy']` then only the other comparison operation is done. The number of columns is close to 50 so it will be impossible to code every pair to ignore in conditional operation.

Edit2:
How do you pass the dummy inside `['a1', 'a2', 'dummy']` ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Create a `Dummy` variable with a class.

If you want a real `Dummy` variable, the official and cleanest way would be to create a class where `__eq__` (equality check) always returns `True`:

```
class Dummy:
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return True
```

And now:

```
>>> df[df['C1'] == Dummy()]
   C1 C2 C3
0  a1  a  d
1  b1  b  e
2  c1  c  f
>>>
```

Always gives `True`.

The `Dummy` class returns `True` for all equality checks.

For the edit.

Just do:

```
['a1', 'a2', Dummy()]
```

#### Use `unittest.mock.any` which does this for us already.

The `unittest` module (builtin module) already done this class for us. We could use that as well:

```
from unittest.mock import ANY
```

And now:

```
>>> df[df['C1'] == ANY]
   C1 C2 C3
0  a1  a  d
1  b1  b  e
2  c1  c  f
>>>
```

Would work too!

**The source code of `unittest.mock.ANY` is the exact same as what I did:**

Getting the source code of `ANY`:

```
import inspect
print(inspect.getsource(ANY.__class__))
```

Output:

```
class _ANY(object):
    "A helper object that compares equal to everything."

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return True

    def __ne__(self, other):
        return False

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<ANY>'
```

It's the same thing as what I did :).

Comment: This is great because it **DOES** return true for nan, which mine doesn't. But mine is smaller ;)

Comment: @user17242583 Well.. Exactly. Mine is just a more official and clean way of doing it.

Comment: @Zanam Btw, there is also a class that already does this for us, check my edit.

Comment: @user17242583 cc.

Answer (score 2):

Why not this?

```py
df[df['C1'] == df['C1']]
```

That will work for all values *except* for NaN, because NaN != NaN.

In fact, because of that very property (perhaps more acurately, *definition*) of NaN, you could do this (although the OP explicitly required solely the use of `==`):

```
df[df['C1'] == np.nan]
```

(I test that, and, as expected, all rows were returned, including NaN ones.)